# Boundary estimates for elliptic systems

Tags: real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Let $ \Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d $ is a $ C^{1,\eta} $ domian with $ 0<\eta<1 $. Assume that $ A(y)=(a_{ij}^{\alpha\beta}(y)) $ is a matrix valued function, where $ 1\leq i,j\leq d $ and $ 1\leq\alpha,\beta\leq m $ with elliptic condition as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda|\xi|^2\leq\sum_{i,j,\alpha,\beta}a_{ij}^{\alpha\beta}(y)\xi_{i}^{\alpha}\xi_{j}^{\beta}\leq\lambda^{-1}|\xi|^2
\end{eqnarray}
for all $ \xi=(\xi_i^{\alpha})\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times d} $ with constant $ \lambda>0 $.
Let $ L=\operatorname{div}(A(x)\nabla) $ be an elliptic operator. Consider the Dirichelt problem as follows
\begin{eqnarray}
Lu&=&0\text{ in }\Omega,\\
u&=&g\text{ on }\partial\Omega,
\end{eqnarray}
where $ g\in C^{0,\sigma} $ with $ 0<\sigma<1 $. I want to ask that if I want to get the Schauder types estimates as
\begin{eqnarray}
\left\|u\right\|_{C^{0,\sigma}(\Omega)}\leq C\left\|g\right\|_{C^{0,\sigma}(\Omega)},
\end{eqnarray}
what conditions should I assume for $ A $. The weaker conditions, the better. I have already know that if $ A\in C^{0,\sigma}(\Omega) $, we can get stronger estimates. I wonder if the condition of $ VMO $  is related to this topic.

Comment: @username Giorgi-Nash-Moser theorem requires that $ m=1 $.

Comment: @username Thank you for your reply, but I find that in the proof of Giorhi-Nash-Moser theorem, we need to estimates functions like $ u^{+} $ the positive parts. However we can not define these for vector-valued functions when $ m\geq 2 $. That is one of the most important differences between the elliptic equations and the elliptic systems.

Comment: Sorry you are right I forgot.